# PHP Reload Variable in array value

Tags: php, arrays, variables, reload

I'm having a little issue with a variable declaration and value inside an array value. Let me explain:

The situation:
I have a 'Require' at the top of my script. Inside this require, there is an array with this content:

```
....    
$oModules[5]['QUERY'] = array(
    'UPDATE voorraad INNER JOIN import_soldenperc ON import_soldenperc.barbodykleur = voorraad.barbodykleur '.(($trigger_filter_store) ? 'AND import_soldenperc.store = voorraad.mag' : '' ) SET voorraad.solden_pct = import_soldenperc.solden_pct, voorraad.solden_vp = 0, voorraad.solden_sta = DATE(import_soldenperc.solden_sta), voorraad.solden_end = DATE(import_soldenperc.solden_end);'
);
....
```

As you can see, there is a Variable 'trigger' inside this array value.

The issue:
This variable gets set after my require

```
    ...
    require_once 'application.php';
    ....
    ....
    foreach($headValue..
       if('store' == $fieldValue){
          $trigger_filter_store = true;
       }
    ...
```

Then at the bottom of my script, there is a function that calls my array value:

```
foreach ($oModules[$_SESSION['module_id']]['QUERY'] as $Query){
    //Execute query
```

The problem:
My **$trigger_filter_store**  variable gets set at the start, together with the require (which parses the array value to a concated string).

How can I *"reload" or "reset"* this [QUERY] string with the updated $trigger_filter_store ?

This is a running script where I can't add a lot of changes, because it's a import page that executes the necessary queries, depending on which module is selected in the application.php module-array and I don't want to "break" the entire array-setup.

The only "simple" solution I thought of, was to require my application.php after the variable has been set, **but I use some functions from the application.php before I set my variable**.

I'm out of ideas really (without breaking the entire script).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use @khuderm solution and use that `require` after setting the variable, or you can do this:

```
$oModules[5]['QUERY'] = array(
    function($trigger_filter_store) {
        return 'UPDATE voorraad INNER JOIN import_soldenperc...';
    }
)
```

and then call the function with `$Query($trigger_filter_store);` in your foreach.

Comment: Perfect! Simple and effective! Thanks! And the reason I can't require after my variable, is because I use some array values before I can set my variable ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the file at the top of the page, move it where you need it so the variable are set first and then you include the file.

Comment: That was my first idea, but the issue then is that I use other values from that array, before I set my variable. So I would have to require 2 different parts before and after setting my variable